# hide forms tab in a form head crm dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

I have an entity which contains 2 forms, I want to prevent navagation between these 2 forms based on the value of two option field. In other words if the value of need prescoring is yes navigation is not possible and the inverse, how can I do this ?

Is it possible to simply hide the list ?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: It's not, because forms depend on security role, not on data. You need to revise the requirements.

Comment: also it's not possile to hide this list ? @Alex

Comment: No, it's not possible in supported way.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot dynamically change the forms the user can select. This can only be done statically based on security roles.

Instead I suggest using a single form, where you hide and show the relevant fields/sections/tabs based on the value of your *Need Processing* field.

Comment: may i redirect the user always to the form pre-scoring if he clicks on the Diligence ? @Henrik H

Comment: You can change forms programmatically. I would recommend against it. Just use at single form where you show/hide stuff, which I personally find easier to maintain (and in this way you can easily re-use elements across use cases)

Answer (score 0):

You can decide based on your project complexity wrt number of form controls/tabs/sections. We did something like this to maintain & forced navigation based on form control value.

```
    var taskFormOptionSet = {
        Form1: 1,
        Form2: 2,
    };

        var FormNames = {
            Form1: "Form1",
            Form2: "Form2",
        };

    var myform = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("need_Prescoring").getValue();
    var currentform = Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.getCurrentItem();

    if (currentform != null) {
        var formId = currentform.getId();
        var formLabel = currentform.getLabel();
    }

    if (myform == taskFormOptionSet.Form1 && formLabel != FormNames.Form1) {
        var items = Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.items.get();
        for (var i in items) {
            var form = items[i];
            var formId = form.getId();
            var formLabel = form.getLabel();

            if (formLabel == FormNames.Form1) {
                form.navigate();
                return;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

As it's not supported I used another solution which is to check if the boolean is true and the name of the, if the user tries to change the form he will be redirected to the right form until he changes the value of the boolean.

```
DiligenceSwitch: function(){
    if (Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.getCurrentItem() != null) {
        var currentform = Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.getCurrentItem();            
    }

    if (currentform != null) {
        var formId = currentform.getId();
        var formLabel = currentform.getLabel();
    }

    var kycId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();        
    SDK.REST.retrieveRecord(kycId, "kyc_Kycdiligence", "kyc_Needprescoring", null,               //field for searching the targeted field, entity, targeted field, ...
        function (kyc) {
            if (kyc != null || kyc.kyc_Needprescoring != null) {
                if (formLabel != "Pre-Scoring" && kyc.kyc_Needprescoring == true) {     
                    var windowOptions = { openInNewWindow: false };
                    var parameters = {};
                    parameters["formid"] = "4B0C88A9-720C-4BFA-8F59-7C1D5DD84F02";
                    Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("kyc_kycdiligence", kycId, parameters, windowOptions);
                    alert("Vous devez faire le pre-scoring");    
                }
            }   
        },
        function (error) {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
        });
},
```

Comment: Did you see my answer? Why are you doing one more service call to retrieve the field value which is available in form readily?

Comment: Because I should get the value onload and sometimes it's null which generates errors, and this field should be hidden in the form @ArunVinoth